# I can't switch account to my facebook page anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger

Before I am able to switch to my facebook page in Messenger Desktop (Windows 11). After I switch to my main account, I can't be able to switch it back to my page.

I hope anyone can help me with this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while ago it lasted around 4 weeks if you have a CRM like Hootsuite you can switch back into your main page through that for the time being until it fixes itself out.